# isOpened() is always false in Ubuntu 14.04 VM

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I installed opencv recently in my VM.

But in the code, isOpened() function always returns false and I am not able to perform VideoCapture as well as any other things.

Do we have any fix for this?

Comment: Did you checked your VM could access to the video device (your camera)? I think this issue is more related with VM things.

Comment: I have seen this issue before. This is not an openCV problem. Your VM cannot access your device camera. I'd recommend that you install Ubuntu on your machine in dual-boot mode instead of using VM